# Scan through text and convert anything green to white and back again

Tags: javascript, pdf, button, adobe, acrobat

I've been using Adobe Acrobat DC to edit pdfs, and I want to insert a button (JavaScript) in which it turns anything in green text [RGB,0,0.56,0] to white [RGB,1,1,1]. However, I'm struggling how to do this. I'm not familiar with Javascript.

Comment: Are you trying to modify page content using Acrobat JavaScript? If that's the case, you can't. You can only modify text field properties and annotations.

Comment: I have a 200 page pdf with text (mixture of green, and black) in it, I'd like to be able to convert all the green text in that page or in the whole document using Javascript. I was hoping to find an easier way using a button rather than highlighting the text and then manually changing the colours (that would take a a good few hours)